# No RCTConvert UIView function found

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to allow a custom property to my bridged view. The property should be an element wrapped in a  so like this:

```
<SheetView child={<View><Text>rawr</Text></View} />
```

However this is causing the error:

> No +[RCTConvert UIView:] function found.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

My `SheetViewModule.m` code is set like this:

```
#import "SheetViewModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(SheetViewManager, RCTViewManager)

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(txt, NSString);
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(child, UIView);

@end
```

and `SheetViewModule.h`:

```
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>

@interface SheetViewModule : RCTViewManager

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *txt;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIView *child;

@end
```

May you please help me fix this error.

It seems they had the same error here - https://github.com/kayla-tech/react-native-card-io/issues/12 - but they never solved it, just removed it.

We also see that it is used as prop here by the official react-native Navigator component - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Views/RCTNavigator.h#L18

Comment: Was React Native working in your project before adding this?  Is it a native base project or React Native base project?  Can you show me the pod file if you used that to install to a native application ?

Comment: @agibson007 yep - it actually still works, its just that I am not able to pass a `<View>` as a prop.

Comment: oh i see.  sorry for the misunderstanding.  does it work just to wrap <Sheetview><View/></Sheetview>.  Or just passing the items needed and constructing the views in the native side.  sorry i have never passed child views to a native component only data.

Comment: Thank you sir very much for your attention. I did not pass it as child, but I will try and get back to you. :)